# The amp-next-page functionality does not work, namely loading the following content

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have a problem, I wanted to implement an endless news feed using amp-next page. But I faced a problem that after the user scrolls to the very last post, no new data is loaded. Here is the code I used.
//Page

```
<amp-next-page src={http://localhost:3000/api/getInfinitiveTape?page=${page}&locale=${router.locale}}></amp-next-page>
```

I take the data from the api that I get through the next js request. Here I reformat the data I got from the api and embed it as written in the amp documentation

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) {const { locale = '', page = 1 } = req.query;

const data = await apiGetOnePost({page: parseInt(page as string),limit: 1,},locale as string);

const item = transformArticle(data, moduleId);

const baseUrl = req.headers.host;const pageUrl = req.url;const baseProtocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];

if (!baseUrl) {res.status(500).json({message: 'baseUrl is not defined',});return;}

const requestUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

const nextUrl = new URL(requestUrl);nextUrl.pathname = '/api/getInfinitiveTape';nextUrl.searchParams.set('page', String(Number(page) + 1));nextUrl.searchParams.set('locale', 'uk');

const url = new URL(requestUrl);

url.pathname = cosmetology/${item.seo?.[slug_${locale}] as string}/amp;

res.status(200).json({pages: [{...item,image: ${item.s3}${item.image},title: item.title as string,url: url.toString(),},],next: nextUrl.toString(),});}
```

At the end of this route, I get the following json

```
  { pages: 
     [ 
      { 
        id: 5037, 
        title: "test", 
        sub_title: "subtest", 
        publication_date: "2023-03-08", 
        image: "/images/News/test.jpg",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/mySite/siteSlug/amp"
      }
     ],
    next: "http://localhost:3000/api/getInfinitiveTape?page=2&locale=uk"
    }
```

The problem is that when I scroll to the end of the main article, I have an article loaded from amp-next-page, but when I scroll down this article, the next json, link to which I specified in the next attribute does not load

When scrolling to the last article in an infinite feed, automatically load the following json with data